# K framework installation repeatedly fails on MacBookPro 19 OS X Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: homebrew, z3, kframework

I am trying to install Kframework without success. I installed all the dependencies following instructions at https://github.com/kframework/k/tree/master#prerequisite-install-guide and updated the environment variables as suggested.

I have export PATH="~/z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin:$PATH" .
I am running:
brew uninstall kframework
brew uninstall z3, and uninstall the version installed outside of brew
brew clean && brew update && brew upgrade
brew install z3 kframework

Brew install kframework produces the following warning about Command Line Tools:
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install

and eventually ends with

<<< ERROR!
143 org.kframework.utils.errorsystem.KEMException: [Error] Critical: Could not start z3 pr  ocess (IOException: Cannot run program "z3": error=2, No such file or directory)(Even though my CLT are up to date and installed in the right place ).

1. My CommanLineTools seem legit. I have Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C505),
   and have installed CommanLineTools from a binary I downloaded from apple development site Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.3.1.dmg

Typing "xcode-select -p" gives
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

2. my z3 is : z3 -version
   Z3 version 4.8.7 - 64 bit (binary downloaded from z3 website) .

I tried this also with Z3 version  4.8.12

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Are you installing Z3 using Homebrew, or by downloading it manually? Your `PATH` setting and `brew` invocations seem to conflict on this.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I actually tried both options, installing Z3 using homebrew, and downloading it manually.

Comment: I first tried option A (where brew installs z3 4.8.12 
brew install z3 kframework
 The first error I see is:

==> mvn package -DskipTests -Dproject.build.type=FastBuild
Last 15 lines from /Users/Liuba/Library/Logs/Homebrew/kframework/02.mvn:
[INFO] Total time:  09:48 h
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-23T17:24:47-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (build-haskell) on project haskell-backend: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1

Comment: followed by Error: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force …..
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1.

Comment: I then tried option B with manual downloadingexport PATH="~/z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin:$PATH" in my script.
 git clone https://github.com/kframework/k.git
cd k
mvn package

Comment: Here first error is:
 <<< FAILURE! - in org.kframework.parser.inner.disambiguation.AddEmptyListsTest
testArgumentAnnListVar(org.kframework.parser.inner.disambiguation.AddEmptyListsTest)  Time elapsed: 0.388 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.kframework.utils.errorsystem.KEMException: [Error] Internal: Unexpected EOF reached while waiting for response from z3.